# What is the best data types for primary key when your data are more than 2 billion records?

Tags: mysql

From my research most of the article suggest **INT** and few suggest **UUID**. But **INT** are limited to **2,147,483,647** only. what is my records are more than that.

I am taking facebook as an example here. Facebook has over 2 billion users. let say each of the user do a post each week. So the facebook post database will reach its limit if the primary key was **INT**.

**INT** are also easily predictable. if there is `/users/1` than some one can predict and go to the route that they are not supposed to go. e.g `/users/2`.

After reading about UUID. Many says that not to use **UUID**. This is because the size is big and it cost us the performance when do query.

Are facebook using **INT** or string as primary key?

I am still not sure what is the best data types for primary key if the db records are big.

UPDATE:

After researching more and more about Database, I have decided to go for MongoDB for my use case. Which is a NoSql database. Where is MongoDB query are much faster compare to MySql which depend on the primary key type.

Comment: Check [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) size. How threatened do you feel of running out of numbers?

Comment: You could use a BIGINT if you need bigger numbers than INT can hold, also you can make INT unsigned to double the effective (positive) INT range. But if you don't want any predictability you will have to use UUID (or combine INT with another field like a timestamp).

Comment: Facebook is not using a sql databases for users, posts etc.

Comment: UUIDs are not unpredictable, just difficult to predict. There is also BIGINT which has pretty much the same performance and convenience as INT, but the range is large enough for any dataset you can store.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. After researching more and more. I have decided to go for MongoDB (NoSql) for my use case.